# Python date conversion failing in for loop

Tags: python, time

I thought I had this done, but something fundamental is tripping me up.

I have a list of dates that looks like this:

```
dates[0:5]

['September 30 2016',
 'September 6 2016',
 'September 13 2016',
 'October 13 2016',
 'October 13 2014']
```

And I want not only to convert them into structured time but also back out into something Excel can understand -- because that's what my collaborators are using and Excel isn't recognizing the above entries, and the 185 others, as dates (for whatever reason ... I tried).

So, I wrote some test code:

```
date_in = time.strptime(dates[3], "%B %d %Y")
date_out = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d", date_in)
print(date_out)

2016-10-13
```

Lovely. But when I put it into a `for` loop to work through the string, I keep getting an error.

Here's the loop:

```
stripped = []
for item in dates:
    raw = time.strptime(item, "%B %d %Y")
    stripped.append(raw)
```

And here's the error:

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains:  updated September 30 2016
```

*Please note I know the `for` loop above does not do what I said I wanted to do: I was trying to get it back to the fail point. My original code was*:

```
for the_date in dates:
    time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d", time.strptime(the_date, "%b %d %Y"))
```

Comment: It seems there is extraneous stuff in your strings, like `"updated September 30 2016"`, can you use a `try: except` and print the offending `item` in the `except` block?

Comment: Thanks for catching the bad formatting in the original question @juanpa.arrivillaga.

Comment: Actually, you were right: the problem lies with the input.

Answer (score 1):

You have a minor mistake in the format. Just change the format from `"%b %d %Y"` to `"%B %d %Y"`. In addition I add a short snippet:

```
import time

dates = [
    'September 30 2016',
    'September 6 2016',
    'September 13 2016',
    'October 13 2016',
    'October 13 2014']

#                                                      ↓
print([time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d", time.strptime(date, "%B %d %Y")) for date in dates])

# ['2016-09-30', '2016-09-06', '2016-09-13', '2016-10-13', '2014-10-13']
```

Comment: The minor mistake was in my transcribing the code and not simply copying and pasting: I added the error as I posted the question! Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

[juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga) has it right. I changed the code to include `try/except`:

```
for item in dates:
    try:
        raw = time.strptime(item, "%B %d %Y")
        stripped.append(raw)
    except ValueError:
        print(item, dates.index(item))
```

And I've got data/input issues that I hadn't seen. (That's what I get for working too quickly.)

Here are the first three, for the record:

```
August 26 2016 updated September 30 2016 23
Septmeber 1 2016 25
12/1/2016 46
```

Now that juanpa has me realizing I can use `try/except` I'll add some code to change those dates like the third line to the format I want and to leave the really wacky lines alone.